# How to force MS Access to use the same session for queries in a transaction?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, dao

We've migrated data from MS Access to MS SQL Server.
Reports/queries/forms are still in an Access database.
Tables were linked by specifying DSN-less ODBC Connection string.

The thing is that when we have a code like this:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb()

BeginTran
db.Execute("update table set field=" & value & " where condition") #  updating some data (query #1)
db.OpenRecordset("select * from table where field=" & value, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges) # reading just updated data (query #2)
```

the second query fails with a timeout exception.
I looked at active queries via SSMC and found out that query #1 was executed in a different session than query #2 (and both began a transaction)

as SQL Server has READ COMMITTED as a default isolation level, the second query waits for the first query to commit/rollback the transaction and to release a lock while the code waits for the second query to return something.

Is there a way to resolve this issue **without** changing the logic (we still need to read the data that we just have updated.

Comment: "DNS-less ODBC Connection string." - I think you mean "DSN-less" (DSN = Data Source Name).

Comment: Please post more context to the code you've posted, such as the entire function/sub. What exactly is `db` (is it an `RDSServer.DataFactory` or `RDS.DataControl` or something else?)

Comment: @Dai I've updated the code. And yes, of course, it's DSN-less :)

Comment: What language is this code? Is this your actual code? Do you really have table named `table` and field named `field`? Surely you don't really have `where condition` in SQL.

Comment: There is no create reocordset in DAO. That code looks wrong. That should be OpenRecordset.